# Particular Case of Window Functions RANK(), DENSE_RANK() , etc

Tags: sql, function, rank, row-number, dense-rank

I'm looking to obtain the three last `Tax Numbers` associated to each `Email` ranked by column `Created Date`.
For example:

```
Email           Tax N°  Created Date    Rank
dam_10@o.com    708157054   27-09-16    1
dam_10@o.com    708157054   27-09-16    1
dam_10@o.com    21714574    27-08-16    2
dam_10@o.com    21714574    27-08-16    2
dam_10@o.com    21714574    27-08-16    2
dam_10@o.com    21714574    27-08-16    2
dam_10@o.com    21714574    24-08-16    2
dam_10@o.com    20222011877 04-08-15    3
dam_10@o.com    20222011877 04-08-15    3
dam_10@o.com    33546663669 28-08-13    4
dam_10@o.com    30523312398 28-08-13    5
dam_10@o.com    30523312398 28-08-13    5
est_20@r.com    123722900   28-08-13    1
est_20@r.com    512381112   28-08-13    2
```

I tried using window function **`DENSE_RANK()`**, but I couldn't debug the case where the `Created Date` was different, but same `Tax Number`:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY M.[Email] ORDER BY A.[Created Date] DESC, A.[Tax Number] DESC) AS [Ranking]
```

[It should be Rank 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ5C4.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing the following function first `MAX(A.[Created Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Email], [Tax Number]) AS [Last Created Date]`